# Understanding Latitude Jumps

Tags: gps, ais

I'm decoding some AIS messages and outputting KML files showing routes. Looking at some ships in the Adriatic Sea there are some weird Latitude jumps that I don't understand. 
[image]

- Several ships show similar anomalies correlating to Latitude information.

  Some ship's position jumps are:

  45.73537 , 13.63126
  -45.141627 , 13.631353
  45.734942 ,  13.63136

  45.641197 , 13.745698
  -34.749633 , 13.745702
  45.641188 , 13.745702

  45.637602 , 13.75268
  -20.772212 , 13.752528
  45.637602 , 13.75268

  45.612017, 13.7784
  -93.531987, 59.310132
  45.61205, 13.7784

So I'm wondering if this is a GPS error, or an AIS error ? or what are some other possibilities ?

Comment: Are the jumps present in the raw AIS data? Are they randomly or evenly spaced - both in terms of real time between 'errors' and number of observations.

Comment: this sounds more like a software/hardware question than GIS. The GIS part of this question is only pos/neg latitudes are going to be in northern and southern hemispheres. what is causing it seems to have very little if anything to do with GIS. Can you make your question have to do with GIS?

Comment: @Mikkel Lydholm Rasmussen the locations are from decoded raw AIS messages, they're plotted according to transmission time (epoch time included with exact earth)

Comment: @Brad Nesom I figured the question involved GIS with the inclusion of KML mapping and the question involving geographic information. If there's a more relevant stack site let me know.

Comment: @cat_bug we prefer responses to "questions in comments" should go toward "edits" in the original question to enhance the question to make it fit this format. I think the question you commented on is asking can you see the raw data? Is it showing S-Hemis lats? If so, you should look to AIS for an answer. Also explain the decoding process.

Comment: I have worked on AIS in the past. If memory serves me correctly it uses two's complement to encode the position in the message, so it would only require a one bit change to go from +ve to -ve. We used to get quite a few odd readings, as there is no error correction mechanism built into the message, so we just used to discard anything that was a fair distance away from the receiver in question (there range only being about 20km or so). If you have mostly sensible readings showing progress along a route, I would just mark it down to occasional noise and ignore.

Comment: @John Barça thanks ! I wrote a program that flags mmsi with a similar criteria (if a transmission is 60 miles away and it's been less than an hour it is flagged). I have found errors when ships cross the meridian/equator likely due to 2's compliment. I was just thinking with all these similar errors if it's possible that a GPS anomaly was happening similar to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43613/why-does-gps-altitude-jump-sometimes   (affecting latitude opposed to alitutde)

Comment: Yes, also quite likely to be a GPS anomaly. I would say ignore if the percentage is low -- it is inevitable you are going to get some errors.

Comment: There is no reason that GPS yields those jumps (affecting altitude instead of latitude would not create jumps). You could have GPS errors, but not of this large range. One GPS could have a bug, but if this occurs on different ships this is very unlikely. I've never worked with AIS, but it look like a sign error in most cases. Also, latitude -93 does not exist.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. 
Ideally, questions should stand on their own, without comment.
Please **[edit]** the extra information, provided in comments, into the body of the question. (And edit "longitude" in 2nd sentence.)