# Mobile phone GPS altitude decreases when measured from high rise buildings

Tags: gps, datum, mobile, altitude

I am using my mobile phone ([Motorola G30](https://m.gsmarena.com/motorola_moto_g30-10724.php)) in which I had installed [GPS Test app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chartcross.gpstest), to measure altitude. I am coming across something really weird. Attached is the screengrab comparing the altitude reported from the same location, but from different floors. One would expect the altitude reported to rise as one move from 4th floor of a building to 6th floor. But it appears to fall. Why is this happening?

[image: altitude delta]

The measurements were made from the building's porch/balcony. So visibility was no issue.
I have observed this to happen in many cases. What could be the reason?
I did try to change the datum correction but still, the altitude reported would fall whenever I climb up a building or a structure. I cross checked the other most relevant question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43613/why-does-gps-altitude-jump-sometimes), but it does not answer my question.

Comment: Did your GPS app give you some mesure of error (PDOP or GDOP for exemple), if yes check that to see of your position is good (GDOP should be below 6, if greater than 10 it's really bad...). If the color are indicator of satellite reception you have more red than green so your position could be bad.... Also if you are in the same spot but different level you should get the same lat/lon  check that is the case

Comment: I get SNR per satellite and overall accuracy (in meters) of the position calculated. I am not sure if the app I am using gives ang PDOP or GDOP data. I will try to look it up

Answer (score 1):

GNSS used in mobile phones can give reasonable positioning accuracy under good conditions, but the GNSS antennas are very small which means accuracy degrades quickly in poor conditions.  You are trying to use the GNSS in VERY poor conditions - GNSS multipath right next to a vertical concrete structure is very high which will give poor accuracy.

So what you are seeing is just GNSS error.  Even if you used a survey-grade GNSS with a good antenna, you would still get poor accuracy on the balcony of a high-rise building.

Comment: I can say that the velocity measured and location position when on ground level are very accurate while I am using the mobile based GNSS. It's the altitude which was causing the trouble. I noticed this when I tried to measure the height of a building using the GPS data and got a good laugh out of my friends

Comment: Moving between 4th floor and 6th floor will contribute to poor positioning on the balcony - when you go inside the building to elevator or stairs, the GNSS will stop tracking all GNSS satellites and only start tracking when you get on the other balcony, typically early positions after starting to track are poor.  Usually positions improve over time (so your altitude should improve after 5 or 10 minutes on the balcony) but some GNSS have a feature called "static positioning" where they decide velocities are low so they keep the same position.